# how to use a old version react library with the latest react version project

Tags: reactjs, npm, canvas, annotations, bounding-box

I want to use this **react-image-annotation** from npm, as this uses **React Version 16.3** i get errors when trying installing, i use **React version 18.2.0**,
this package :https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image-annotation

Error:

```
$ npm install --save react-image-annotation
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: vision@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.3" from react-image-annotation@0.9.10
npm ERR! node_modules/react-image-annotation
npm ERR!   react-image-annotation@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /home/x/.npm/_logs/2023-05-10T07_41_23_099Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/x/.npm/_logs/2023-05-10T07_41_23_099Z-debug-0.log
```

My code where i want to render bounding-box and polygon based on coordinates:

```
function ReviewMediaBox({ id, mediaUrl, mediaType, handleImageLoading, isPreviousDisabled, lowerBoxHeight, handlePrevious, handleNext }: ReviewMediaProps) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const isFullscreen = useSelector((state: any) => state.global.isReviewFullscreen);
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState<boolean>(true);
  const [playedSeconds, setPlayedSeconds] = useState<number>(0);
  const isVideo: boolean = mediaType === "IMAGE" ? false : true;
  const videoRef = useRef<ReactPlayer>(null);
  const canvasRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null);


  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col items-center">
      <div className={` w-full flex flex-col items-center justify-center rounded-lg px-5 ${lowerBoxHeight && !isFullscreen ? "xxl:h-[40.5rem] h-[30rem] kk:h-[69.5vh]" : !isFullscreen ? "xxl:h-[68vh] h-[65vh] kk:h-[76vh] " : "xxl:h-[79vh] h-[65vh] kk:h-[76vh]"} `}>
        {/* videoBox */}
        {isVideo ? (
          <ReactPlayer
            url={mediaUrl}
            playing={isPlaying}
            onEnded={handleVideoEnded}
            onProgress={handleProgress}
            width="100%"
            height="100%"
            ref={videoRef}
            onLoad={() => handleImageLoading()}
          />
        ) : (
          <TransformWrapper
          // centerOnInit={true}
          >
            <TransformComponent>
              <LazyLoadImage
                src={mediaUrl}
                alt="image"
                loading="lazy"
                onLoad={() => handleImageLoading()}
                className={`relative rounded-md image-component`}
              />
              {/* canvas */}
              <canvas
                ref={canvasRef}
                style={{ position: "absolute", height: "inherit", width: "100%", background: "rgba(56, 255, 0, 0.11)" }}
              ></canvas>
            </TransformComponent>
          </TransformWrapper>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default ReviewMediaBox;
```

i tried installing by adding
**--force** but failed; what are the posibilities to use that library